# Prove that the set of functions is uncountable using Cantor's diagonal argument

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that the **set of all functions from the set of even numbers into $\{a, b, c \}$ is uncountable**.

I know I need to treat functions as series and start from there somehow (similarly to proving that set of $f: N \to \{0,1\}$ is uncountable) but I am having a problem with applying Cantor's diagonal argument in this particular case.

Can you please give me any hints?

Comment: Could you please show how far in with the proof you can get?

Comment: Hint: Ignore the third element $c$ and think of $\{a,b\}$ as $\{0,1\}$. Think of the even numbers $\{2n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ as $\mathbb{N}$ (which is possible because both are infinite countable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should realize is that each such function is also a sequence.

The diagonal arguments works as you assume an enumeration of elements and thereby create an element from the diagonal, different in every position and conclude that that element hasn't been in the enumeration.

To be concrete assume that $f_n$ is such an enumeration and consider the function

$$\phi(2n) = \begin{cases}b & \mbox{if } f_n(2n) = a\\ a & \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Since $\phi(2n) \ne f_n(2n)$ we have that $\phi\ne f_n$.